# Facet_grid output in more than one window

Tags: r, window, facet, ggplot2

My code:

```
ggplot(data=ICL3, aes(x=as.Date(AÑO_MES), y=IndICL3, group=RUN_FM, colour=RUN_FM)) +
  labs(colour = "RUN Fondos") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 150)) + 
  xlab("Periodo") + ylab("% Cobertura")  +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=100),colour="red",size=1.2) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="smooth", size=1, mapping = aes (group = 1),colour="green") + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(RUN_FM ~ SERIE)
```

`Facet_grid` is plotting all the results in one window which consist in more than 100 tables, which obviously looks awful and is unintelligible.

Is there a way to put a condition on the number of tables, and plot the results in more than 1 window? Or do I have to manually split the data for comprehensible graphics?

Comment: You could use ggsave and make a huge image or split it like @metasequia suggested in his or her answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I can think of is saving subsets of your total facet series.

Without a reproducible dataset, I can only suggest that you

1) look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608133/plot-only-a-select-few-facets-in-facet-grid) for how to subset data for facets (two at a time?)

2) wrap a `for` loop or `lapply()` function around a plot call and `ggsave()`

```
try(ggsave(file = paste(<some directory>,<some changing file name>,".png">),
    height=y,width=x))
```